# JMeter Slave is unable to use the CSV when the count of Slaves are increasing

Tags: testing, jmeter, distributed, master-slave

The load is 1000Threads from each instances. When I'm trying with 1 Master & 3 Slaves the jmeter is able to correctly use the CSV for slave instances however when the slaves are increasing , the JMeter is skipping the Thread groups which require CSV.

I tried increasing the heap to 14Gb where the Memory is 16GB.I'm unable to figure out why the JMeter is skipping the Threads in Slave instance which are using CSV.

Answer (score 0):

In current form the question doesn't provide enough level of details to be comprehensively answered.

First guess would be: you just forgot to copy the CSV file to "new" slaves, as per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html):

> If the test uses any data files, **note that these are not sent across by the client so make sure that these are available in the appropriate directory on each server**

You can also check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) on the slave machines, it should contain messages regarding thread start and stop events or inability to start/stop the thread. [JMeter Logging verbosity can be increased](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) if log file is not very informative with default logging configuration.

With regards to allocating 14 GB out of 16 to JMeter it might not be the best idea as larger heap will require more time for the [garbage collection](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html). It won't ruin your test but you may have not relevant results. So consider keeping heap occupancy between 30 and 80%.